# Operational issue for scheduling mongodump as backup method

Tags: backup, mongodb, mongodb-3.0, mongodb-3.2

For production backup, MongoDB recommends [mongodump](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/#considerations) instead of [mongoexport](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/program/mongoexport/) for accuracy of data. However, a few operational issue remain unclear to me, appreciate if anyone can advise on this matter.

### Logging

How to redirect mongodump's progress log into a file or some other repository rather than stdout? I tried the following code but it simply output an empty file and all logs remain in stdout.

```
mongodump --host MONGO --out %FULLPATH% --oplog >> out.log
```

### Error Handling and Retry

Does mongodump return some error code when it failed? I used windows task scheduler to run mongodump and it always consider the job has been run successfully while mongodump may have failed silently.

I'm running this in Windows.

Comment: Which version of mongodb are you using?

Comment: Both 3.0 and 3.2